# How to set Repeatinterval to Two Minutes in Iphone SDK?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How to set LocalNotification repeat each two minutes?

Following is my code at moment.

localNotification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit;

is there anything like

localNotification.repeatInterval = NSMinuteCalendarUnit * 2; to set it called after.

Anything like this is available.

Please note i have read few 2008 based post to make this happen but at that time this was not available and few guys requested apple to do so. So if this is up now.

Let me know,
Thanks
Jigar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `repeatInterval` property can only be set to a `NSCalendarUnit`.
There is no way to set it to 2 minutes since this is not a `NSCalendarUnit`.

Your options are:

- `NSEraCalendarUnit`
- `NSYearCalendarUnit`
- `NSMonthCalendarUnit`
- `NSDayCalendarUnit`
- `NSHourCalendarUnit`
- `NSMinuteCalendarUnit`
- `NSSecondCalendarUnit`
- `NSWeekCalendarUnit`
- `NSWeekdayCalendarUnit`

Or you can set a second `UILocalNotification` which fires after two minutes after the first one.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html